# java repaint multiple area

Tags: java, swing

I want to draw specific area on JPanel, like this (black area is where I want JPanel to be repainted):

[image]

Below code is how I implemented this. It follows mouse cursor and draws a circle at the mouse cursor point. The size of frame and panel is 300*300.

```
public class MiniGraphicTest extends JPanel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public int x,y;
public MiniGraphicTest() {
    super();
    x = -1;
    y = -1;
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent m){
            x = m.getX()-25;
            y = m.getY()-25;
            repaint(100,100,100,100);
            repaint(200,200,100,100);
        }
    });
}
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //////////////////////
    //DO NOT MODIFY HERE//
    //////////////////////
    //Draw gridline
    int width = this.getWidth();
    int height = this.getHeight();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for(int i=100;i<width;i+=100){
        g.drawLine(i, 0, i, height);
    }
    for(int i=100;i<height;i+=100){
        g.drawLine(0, i, width, i);
    }
    //////////////////////
    //put test code here//
    //////////////////////
    if(x == -1&&y==-1) return;//initially draw nothing
    g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
}
}//main function is just showing the panel. nothing special
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame("Test");
    MiniGraphicTest test = new MiniGraphicTest();
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    jf.setResizable(false);
    jf.add(test);
    jf.pack();
    jf.setVisible(true);
}
```

The result of this code is like this :

[image]

It repaints outside of the area to be repainted. Can you explain me why this happened and how to solve this?

PS. The code completely works well when only single repaint(100,100,100,100) is called in the mouseMoved.

Thank you

Comment: See if this topic may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815493/custom-painting-of-a-swing-component-with-multiple-calls-to-repaint

Comment: draw circle only if mouse is inside the required squares.

Comment: @Berger Thank you for link. I understand that multiple repaint() method will be "somehow processed" and will repaint only once, but it doesn't explain why it repaints undesired area, unless assuming the "process" would include that area.

Comment: @FastSnail That might be a solution, but that's not what my ideal result. What I want is showing circle masked by not repainting area. Maybe my question was somehow absurd. I'll edit my question. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **Fast Snail**'s solution is is the right answer in general. If you have a dynamic situation with dynamic size of the board or so, you may consider **draw circle only if mouse is inside the required squares** as recommended.

Multiple calling `repaint` only makes a bigger area of `repaint` to include all the area's you specified in the multiple calls of `repaint`.

But if you have this little board with 9 cells, I think there is a quick fix for your situation in order not to make subsequent calls for `repaint`:

```
public class MiniGraphicTest extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public int x, y;
    boolean flag;

    public MiniGraphicTest() {
        super();
        x = -1;
        y = -1;
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent m) {
                x = m.getX() - 25;
                y = m.getY() - 25;
                if(flag) {
                    repaint(100, 100, 100, 100);
                } else {
                    repaint(200, 200, 100, 100);
                }
                flag = !flag;
            }
        });
    }
    // Other codes of yours
}
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

`repaint()` only marks the component to be repainted in EDT.
Subsequent calls not changes anything.

Calling `repaint` with coordinates (rectangle) mark the component to be repainted only inside the rect.
Subsequent calls can only change (extend) that rect.

If you want to `clip` drawing to some area, you need to specify that in your `paintComponent` method.